# tmux "Socket is not connected" error on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, tmux

I get the following error when I start a new session in tmux:

```
launch_msg("SetUserEnvironment"): Socket is not connected                                                                                                                         
launch_msg("SetUserEnvironment"): Socket is not connected
```

My info:

- OS X 1.0.7.3
- zsh 4.3.11
- tmux 1.6

Tmux still launches and I haven't had any huge issues, but I'm hoping to get some insight into why this occurs. I've heard installing [tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) "fixes" this message, but I'd rather not install a wrapper if I don't need it's features.

Comment: What are the contents (if any) of your `.tmux.conf` file, and exactly what command are you using to start tmux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error message comes from *launchctl* when its `setenv` command has (apparently) failed to talk to *launchd*.

*tmux* does not automatically use *launchctl*, so you will have to dig into your specific configuration to find the source of the *launchctl* usage. My guess is that you are have one or more `launchctl setenv …` in your shell initialization files.

If you do not care that the *launchctl* invocations are failing, you could just suppress the error message by sending stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
launchctl setenv somevar somevalue 2>/dev/null
```

I had never heard of this particular application for my wrapper, but it does seem to fix the problem (at least here under 10.6).

If you need your *launchctl* invocations to succeed, then you do need the wrapper’s functionality (it is not *just* for pasteboard access; it can help with any functionality that requires access to a service in the “per-user bootstrap namespace”). If you do not want to run your shells “under the wrapper” (as described in its [README](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard#readme)), then you could run just the individual *launchctl* invocations under it:

```
/path/to/reattach-to-user-namespace launchctl setenv somevar somevalue
```

It appears that the wrapper can be easily installed via *MacPort*, and *Homebrew*:

- `port install tmux-pasteboard` (*MacPorts*)
- `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace` (*Homebrew*)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I indeed have `launchctl setenv...` in my zsh init file. I'll work around by sending to stderr. In the future I'll take a look at the wrapper.

Comment: Thank you!  For me, it was the .zlogin file from the default YADR install.  So I piped it to /dev/null like you said.

Comment: BTW I ended up going with the reattach-to-user-namespace wrapper. Good stuff.